# Demystifying sharedctypes performance

Tags: python

In python it is possible to share ctypes objects between multiple processes. However I notice that allocating these objects seems to be extremely expensive.

Consider following code:

```
from multiprocessing import sharedctypes as sct
import ctypes as ct
import numpy as np

n = 100000
l = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=n)

def foo1():
    sh = sct.RawArray(ct.c_int, l)
    return sh

def foo2():
    sh = sct.RawArray(ct.c_int, len(l))
    sh[:] = l
    return sh

%timeit foo1()
%timeit foo2()

sh1 = foo1()
sh2 = foo2()

for i in range(n):
    assert sh1[i] == sh2[i]
```

The output is:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 30.4 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 9.65 ms per loop
```

There are two things that puzzle me:

- Why is explicit allocation and initialization compared to passing a numpy array so much faster?
- Why is allocating shared memory in python so extremely expensive? `%timeit np.arange(n)` only takes `46.4 µs`. There are several orders of magnitude between those timings.

Comment: The difference is quite substantial, the only line that differs in the source is https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py#L66 which is hit when you pass an array

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Sample Code

I rewrote your sample code a little bit to look into this issue. Here's where I landed, I'll use it in my answer below:

`so.py`:

```
from multiprocessing import sharedctypes as sct
import ctypes as ct
import numpy as np

n = 100000
l = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=n)


def sct_init():
    sh = sct.RawArray(ct.c_int, l)
    return sh

def sct_subscript():
    sh = sct.RawArray(ct.c_int, n)
    sh[:] = l
    return sh

def ct_init():
    sh = (ct.c_int * n)(*l)
    return sh

def ct_subscript():
    sh = (ct.c_int * n)(n)
    sh[:] = l
    return sh
```

Note that I added two test cases that do not use shared memory (and use regular a `ctypes` array instead).

`timer.py`:

```
import traceback
from timeit import timeit

for t in ["sct_init", "sct_subscript", "ct_init", "ct_subscript"]:
    print(t)
    try:
        print(timeit("{0}()".format(t), setup="from so import {0}".format(t), number=100))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed:", e)
        traceback.print_exc()
    print

print()

print ("Test",)
from so import *
sh1 = sct_init()
sh2 = sct_subscript()

for i in range(n):
    assert sh1[i] == sh2[i]
print("OK")
```

## Test results

The results from running the above code using Python 3.6a0 (specifically [`3c2fbdb`](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/3c2fbdb)) are:

```
sct_init
2.844902500975877
sct_subscript
0.9383537038229406
ct_init
2.7903486443683505
ct_subscript
0.978101353161037

Test
OK
```

What's interesting is that *if you change `n`*, the results scale linearly. For example, using `n = 100000` (10 times bigger), you get something that's pretty much 10 times slower:

```
sct_init
30.57974253082648
sct_subscript
9.48625904135406
ct_init
30.509132395964116
ct_subscript
9.465419146697968

Test
OK
```

## Speed difference

In the end, the speed difference lies in the hot loop that is called to initialize the array by copying every single value over from the Numpy array (`l`) to the new array (`sh`). This makes sense, because as we noted speed scales linearly with array size.

When you pass the Numpy array as a constructor argument, the function that does this is [`Array_init`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6fd916862e1a93b1578d8eabdefc3979a4d4af62/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#L4213-L4232). However, if you assign using `sh[:] = l`, then it's [`Array_ass_subscript` that does the job](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6fd916862e1a93b1578d8eabdefc3979a4d4af62/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#L4398-L4453).

Again, what matters here are the hot loops. Let's look at them.

`Array_init` hot loop (slower):

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    PyObject *v;
    v = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(args, i);
    if (-1 == PySequence_SetItem((PyObject *)self, i, v))
        return -1;
}
```

`Array_ass_subscript` hot loop (faster):

```
for (cur = start, i = 0; i < otherlen; cur += step, i++) {
    PyObject *item = PySequence_GetItem(value, i);
    int result;
    if (item == NULL)
        return -1;
    result = Array_ass_item(myself, cur, item);
    Py_DECREF(item);
    if (result == -1)
        return -1;
}
```

As it turns out, the majority of the speed difference lies in using `PySequence_SetItem` vs. `Array_ass_item`.

Indeed, if you change the code for `Array_init` to use `Array_ass_item` instead of `PySequence_SetItem` (`if (-1 == Array_ass_item((PyObject *)self, i, v))`), and recompile Python, the new results become:

```
sct_init
11.504781467840075
sct_subscript
9.381130554247648
ct_init
11.625461496878415
ct_subscript
9.265848568174988

Test
OK
```

Still a bit slower, but not by much.

In other words, most of the overhead is caused by a slower hot loop, and mostly caused by [the code that `PySequence_SetItem` wraps around `Array_ass_item`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1364858e6ec7abfe04d92b7796ae8431eda87a7a/Objects/abstract.c#L1584-L1609).

This code might appear like little overhead at first read, but it really isn't.

`PySequence_SetItem` actually calls into the entire Python machinery to resolve the `__setitem__` method and call it.

This *eventually* resolves in a call to `Array_ass_item`, but only after a large number of levels of indirection (which a direct call to `Array_ass_item` would bypass entirely!)

Going through the rabbit hole, the call sequence looks a bit like this:

- `s->ob_type->tp_as_sequence->sq_ass_item` points to [`slot_sq_ass_item`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cca9b8e3ff022d48eeb76d8567f297bc399fec3a/Objects/typeobject.c#L5790-L5803).
- `slot_sq_ass_item` calls into [`call_method`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cca9b8e3ff022d48eeb76d8567f297bc399fec3a/Objects/typeobject.c#L1439-L1471).
- `call_method` calls into [`PyObject_Call`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1364858e6ec7abfe04d92b7796ae8431eda87a7a/Objects/abstract.c#L2149-L2175)
- And on and on until we eventually get to `Array_ass_item`..!

In other words, we have C code in `Array_init` that's calling Python code (`__setitem__`) in a hot loop. That's slow.

### Why ?

Now, why does Python use `PySequence_SetItem` in `Array_init` and not `Array_ass_item` in `Array_init`?

That's because if it did, it would be bypassing the hooks that are exposed to the developer in Python-land.

Indeed, you *can* intercept calls to `sh[:] = ...` by subclassing the array and overriding `__setitem__` (`__setslice__` in Python 2). It will be called once, with a `slice` argument for the index.

Likewise, defining your own `__setitem__` also overrides the logic in the constructor. It will be called N times, with an integer argument for the index.

This means that if `Array_init` directly called into `Array_ass_item`, then you would lose something: `__setitem__` would no longer be called in the constructor, and you wouldn't be able to override the behavior anymore.

Now can we try to retain the faster speed all the while still exposing the same Python hooks?

Well, perhaps, using this code in `Array_init` instead of the existing hot loop:

```
 return PySequence_SetSlice((PyObject*)self, 0, PyTuple_GET_SIZE(args), args);
```

Using this will call into `__setitem__` **once** with a slice argument (on Python 2, it would call into `__setslice__`). We still go through the Python hooks, but we only do it once instead of N times.

Using this code, the performance becomes:

```
sct_init
12.24651838419959
sct_subscript
10.984305887017399
ct_init
12.138383641839027
ct_subscript
11.79078131634742

Test
OK
```

### Other overhead

I think the rest of the overhead may be due to the tuple instantiation that takes place [when calling `__init__` on the array object](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6fd916862e1a93b1578d8eabdefc3979a4d4af62/Lib/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py#L66) (note the `*`, and the fact that `Array_init` expects a tuple for `args`) — this presumably scales with `n` as well.

Indeed, if you replace `sh[:] = l` with `sh[:] = tuple(l)` in the test case, then the performance results become *almost* identical. With `n = 100000`:

```
sct_init
11.538272527977824
sct_subscript
10.985187001060694
ct_init
11.485244687646627
ct_subscript
10.843198659364134

Test
OK
```

There's probably still something smaller going on, but ultimately we're comparing two substantially different hot loops. There's simply little reason to expect them to have identical performance.

I think it might be interesting to try calling `Array_ass_subscript` from `Array_init` for the hot loop and see the results, though!

## Baseline speed

Now, to your second question, regarding allocating shared memory.

Note that there isn't really a cost to allocating *shared* memory. As noted in the results above, there isn't a substantial difference between using shared memory or not.

Looking at the Numpy code (`np.arange` is [implemented here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/eeba2cbfa4c56447e36aad6d97e323ecfbdade56/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L2912-L2930)), we can finally understand why it's so much faster than `sct.RawArray`: **`np.arange` doesn't appear to make calls to Python "user-land"** (i.e. no call to `PySequence_GetItem` or `PySequence_SetItem`).

That doesn't necessarily explain *all* the difference, but you'd probably want to start investigating there.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed analysis! You say `In other words... it looks like the correct behavior here is the slower one!` - This I did not get. Does it mean that the slicing initiation can have unexpected effects?

Comment: @cel My answer wasn't ideal here. The slower behavior is correct, but so is the faster one. I added some detail, and proposed an implementation to have faster *and* correct behavior (though it would still be a breaking change for users that subclassed a `ctypes` array *and* don't handle slices in their `__setitem__` method; I doubt this would be changed in Python — especially considering the presence of a workaround).

Comment: @cel also added another note regarding why the baseline is so slow compared to e.g. `np.arange`. If that's too slow for you, I'd recommend looking into implementing the hot loop in C to cut the corners you can cut.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco this might be one of the best answers I have ever seen. I must have learned a thousand things reading it. A hearty +1!

Comment: Small correction: `PyArray_Arange` is never multithreaded. What you're seeing in that code that you linked to is that while running it drops the GIL. So: `PyArray_Arange` itself only ever uses one thread, but if your Python program has other threads, they can run at the same time that `PyArray_Arange` is running.

Answer (score 7):

Not an answer ([the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33915113/364696) explains this quite well), but for those looking for how to fix this, here's how: **Don't use `RawArray`s slice assignment operator**.

As noted in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33915113/364696), `RawArray`s slice assignment operator doesn't take advantage of the fact that you're copying between two wrappers around C-style arrays of identical type and size. But `RawArray` implements the buffer protocol, so you can wrap it in [a `memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) to access it in an "even more raw" way (and it will make `Foo2` win, because you can only do this after constructing the object, not as part of construction):

```
def foo2():
    sh = sct.RawArray(ct.c_int, len(l))
    # l must be another buffer protocol object w/the same C format, which is the case here
    memoryview(sh)[:] = l
    return sh
```

In tests [solving this problem on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37708824/364696), the time to copy using a `memoryview` wrapper is less than 1% of the time required to copy with `RawArray`s normal slice assignment.
One trick here is that the sizes of the elements of the output of `np.random.randint` are `np.int`, and on a 64 bit system, `np.int` is 64 bits, so on 64 bit Python, you need another round of copying to coerce it to the right size (or you need to declare the `RawArray` to be of a type that matches the size of `np.int`). Even if you do need to make that temporary copy though, it's still much cheaper with a `memoryview`:

```
>>> l = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=100000)
>>> %time sh = sct.RawArray(ct.c_int, len(l))
Wall time: 472 µs  # Creation is cheap

>>> %time sh[:] = l
Wall time: 14.4 ms  # TOO LONG!

# Must convert to numpy array with matching element size when c_int and np.int don't match
>>> %time memoryview(sh)[:] = np.array(l, dtype=np.int32)
Wall time: 424 µs
```

As you can see, even when you need to copy the `np.array` to resize the elements first, the total time is less than 3% of the time required using `RawArray`'s own slice assignment operator.

If you avoid the temporary copy by making the size of the `RawArray` match the source, the cost drops further:

```
# Make it 64 bit to match size of np.int on my machine
>>> %time sh = sct.RawArray(ct.c_int64, len(l))
Wall time: 522 µs  # Creation still cheap, even at double the size

# No need to convert source array now:
>>> %time memoryview(sh)[:] = l
Wall time: 123 µs
```

which gets us down to 0.85% of the `RawArray` slice assignment time; at this point, you're basically running at `memcpy` speeds; the rest of your actual Python code will swamp the miniscule amount of time spent on data copying.

Answer (score 3):

This should be a comment, but I do not have enough reputation :-(

Starting with Python 3.5, shared arrays in Linux are created as temp files mapped to memory (see https://bugs.python.org/issue30919). I think this explains why creating a Numpy array, which is created in memory, is faster than creating and initializing a large shared array.
To force Python to use shared memory, a workaround is to execute these two lines of code (ref. [No space left while using Multiprocessing.Array in shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43573500/no-space-left-while-using-multiprocessing-array-in-shared-memory)):

```
from multiprocessing.process import current_process
current_process()._config['tempdir'] = '/dev/shm'
```

Comment: Don't worry. An enhancement to an existing answer might count as answer too. You wouldn't be able to provide a nicely formatted code sample as comment. So, posting this as answer seems appropriate to me.