# How to write a huge 2D NumPy array into a buffer

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, shared-memory, pyarrow

I have a huge 2D numpy array (dtype=bool) and a buffer and I would like to write this 2D array into the buffer. Currently, I do the following,

```
# Python version 3.7.7, NumPy version 1.18.5
# shape in the dummy_array is just an example, sometimes will be bigger
dummy_array = np.array(np.empty((599066148, 213), dtype='bool'), dtype='bool')

# Pyarrow plasma store buffer
buf = client.create(object_id, dummy_array.nbytes)

# Get a NumPy view of the buffer
array = np.frombuffer(buf, dtype="bool").reshape(dummy_array.shape)

# Write the data or the NumPy array to the buffer
array[:] = dummy_array
```

The problem is that this takes at least 3 minutes. The size of the `dummy_array` is usually 100 to 200GB and sometimes even more. I could not figure out how to do this using `memoryview` and `np.ctypeslib.as_array(buf, shape=dummy_array.shape)` as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37705974/5336958) for a 2D array (I tried, but it did not work). Any pointers to do this in a better or faster way would be great because I will be doing this at least few hundred times, so, saving even 30 to 60 seconds per iteration would save hours.

Comment: So you're running this on a node with 200+ GB of RAM?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Yes, a compute server. It has 1TB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a multi dimensioned memoryview slice.

```
NotImplementedError: memoryview slice assignments are currently restricted to ndim = 1
```

So you might need to reshape your array to be one dimensional before copying it into a memoryview.

```
>>> dummy_array = np.array(np.empty((2, 213), dtype='bool'), dtype='bool').reshape(2*213)
>>> mem = memoryview(dummy_array)
>>> mem[0]
True
>>> np.frombuffer(mem, dtype="bool").reshape(dummy_array.shape)
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,
```

If you try to use multidimensional, you'll get this error.

```
>>> dummy_array = np.array(np.empty((2, 213), dtype='bool'), dtype='bool')
>>> mem = memoryview(dummy_array)
>>> mem[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NotImplementedError: multi-dimensional sub-views are not implemented
```

I can't tell you if this will be faster than your other method but it may give you some ideas for how to get the memoryview version working.