# No space left while using Multiprocessing.Array in shared memory

Tags: python, arrays, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am using the multiprocessing functions of Python to run my code parallel on a machine with roughly 500GB of RAM. To share some arrays between the different workers I am creating a `Array` object:

```
N = 150
ndata = 10000
sigma = 3
ddim = 3

shared_data_base = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_double, ndata*N*N*ddim*sigma*sigma)
shared_data = np.ctypeslib.as_array(shared_data_base.get_obj())
shared_data = shared_data.reshape(-1, N, N, ddim*sigma*sigma)
```

This is working perfectly for `sigma=1`, but for `sigma=3` one of the harddrives of the device is slowly filled, until there is no free space anymore and then the process fails with this exception:

```
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

Now I've got 2 questions:

1. Why does this code even write anything to the disc? Why isn't it all stored in the memory?
2. How can I solve this problem? Can I make Python store it entireley in the RAM without writing it to the HDD? Or can I change the HDD on which this array is written?

**EDIT**: I found something online which suggests, that the array is stored in the "shared memory". But the `/dev/shm` device has plenty more free space as the `/dev/sda1` which is filled up by the code above.
[Here](https://gist.github.com/FlashTek/2688171c3ff46ccc1a35cdd73d54fb06) is the (relevant part of the) strace log of this code.

**Edit #2**: I think that I have found a workarround for this problem. By looking at the source I found that `multiprocessing` tries to create a temporary file in a directory which is determinded by using

```
process.current_process()._config.get('tempdir')
```

Setting this value manually at the beginning of the script

```
from multiprocessing import process
process.current_process()._config['tempdir'] =  '/data/tmp/'
```

seems to be solving this issue. But I think that this is not the best way to solve it. So: are there any other suggestions how to handle it?

Comment: Run it under `strace` to see what is going on.

Comment: BTW, where can one get 500G of RAM? :)

Comment: Also error code might be wrong. And really meaning out of memory. I. e. python library abuses that code.

Comment: My guess is that `multiprocessing.Array()` uses `/dev/shm`, which (at least on Linux) is limited to half the available RAM (check with `df -kh /dev/shm`). Look [here](http://www.walkernews.net/2010/05/04/how-to-resize-devshm-filesystem-in-linux/) on how to increase it (if that's the limiting factor).

Comment: Are you sure `sizeof(c_double) * ndata*N*N*ddim*sigma*sigma` fits into your RAM?

Comment: @robertklep `df` prints: `tmpfs           253G   88K  253G   1% /dev/shm` - so this does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: @FlashTek yeah I _just_ realized that it's an actual disk that's filling up, not a ram-backed device.

Comment: You said about a harddrive being filled. Do you know which one specificly?

Comment: @Igor See my edit.

Comment: How about taking a look at Python Multiprocessing source code?

Comment: I am still curious why the array is even written to the HDD - what's the purpose of this?

Comment: FYI. I am getting this error with Python now and I tried your solution `process.current_process()._config['tempdir'] =  '/data/tmp/'` where in my case I pointed it to a folder with LOT of space. But I still get this error I am afraid. So it looks like something else is causing this.  Python 3.11.3. I am running this inside a Virtual box. But I do not think will have anything to do with this.

Comment: Btw, does it make a difference if this command `process.current_process()._config['tempdir'] =  '/data/tmp/'` is issued in just `__main_` function? that is where  I used it. Or does it have to be also issued inside the function which the process starts? (i.e. in the subprocess?)

Comment: Consider accepting my answer if it helped; otherwise, let me know what I can do to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

These data are larger than 500GB. Just `shared_data_base` would be 826.2GB on my machine by `sys.getsizeof()` and 1506.6GB by `pympler.asizeof.asizeof()`. Even if they were only 500GB, your machine needs some of that memory in order to run. This is why the data are going to disk.

```py
import ctypes
from pympler.asizeof import asizeof
import sys


N = 150
ndata = 10000
sigma = 3
ddim = 3
print(sys.getsizeof(ctypes.c_double(1.0)) * ndata*N*N*ddim*sigma*sigma)
print(asizeof(ctypes.c_double(1.0)) * ndata*N*N*ddim*sigma*sigma)
```

Note that on my machine (Debian 9), /tmp is the location that fills. If you find that you must use disk, be certain that the location on disk used has enough available space, typically /tmp isn't a large partition.