# Unable to install Miniconda due to "no space left on device"

Tags: python, linux, installation, miniconda, anaconda3

I'm attempting to install `Miniconda` remotely on a computer cluster. I've downloaded the Miniconda3 Linux 64-bit installer from [here](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html#linux-installers), and validated the SHA256 hash with `sha256sum ./path_to_installer.sh`. I'm installing in `/home/my_username/`, and I've checked my available disk space with `dg -h /home/my_username/`, which returns:

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
nfs-6-v2669:/mnt/home  9.5T  7.5T  2.0T  79% /home
```

...and my disk quota on the cluster with `grep my_username /home/quota/quote`, which returns:

```
my_username        3.95G   15G
```

When I attempt to install, I'm met with the error:

```
Unpacking payload ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "entry_point.py", line 59, in <module>
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 649, in __init__
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 168, in __init__
  File "multiprocessing/queues.py", line 43, in __init__
  File "multiprocessing/context.py", line 68, in Lock
  File "multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 162, in __init__
  File "multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 57, in __init__
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[21083] Failed to execute script 'entry_point' due to unhandled exception!
```

...while I clearly have more than enough disk space for installation. Some similar posts have suggested that the downloaded installation file is corrupted, however (as previously mentioned) I've verified the SHA256 checksum, and I've tried removing and re-downloading several times.

What is the source of this error?

Comment: Did you look up the code?  That's trying to create semaphore locks.  Perhaps you're not allowed to create locks, or are limited to less than 100.

Comment: Ah, I see. Where does one go to look these up? Google turns up nothing for me. @TimRoberts

Comment: Check here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70175977/multiprocessing-no-space-left-on-device